# InstantiationException when using traversedElement

Tags: orientdb

I'm attempting to setup a Graph which allows a query to follow "Redirect" edges from one vertex to another.

Vertices can only have a single Redirect edge going out; however, there may be a chain of Redirects that occur before reaching the final destination.

I'm attempting to grab the final vertex using the `traversedElement` function; however, even when I strip my implementation down to a query as simple as

`select traversedElement(-1) from (traverse out() from #15:2)`

I'm receiving the following error:

`java.lang.InstantiationException: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.functions.coll.OSQLFunctionTraversedElement`

I'm not sure what the best way to debug this one might be, the simplified query I'm attempting above appears to match the documentation faithfully (documentation example):

`SELECT traversedElement(-1) FROM ( TRAVERSE out() from #34:3232 WHILE $depth <= 10 )`

Any words of wisdom would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue with `traversedElement()` on last release (fixed on 2.0.7-SNAPSHOT). However you can use `traversedEdge()` and `traversedVertex()` that works.

Comment: It's a pleasure meet new users :-)